# Wordpress Plugin Development Question!

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I am currently writing a plugin for my client in wordpress. The issue I am having is when a user clicks on edit to change a record I am not sure how to create the admin link to do this.

i.e.

```
<a href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('url'); ?>/wp-admin/admin.php?page=wpsc_product_seo_details">Edit</a>


function wpsc_product_seo_details()
{
    echo "<h2>Hello</h2>";
}
```

I know my markup for the  tag is probably wrong but I was just testing. Do I need to register a hook to do this.

Comment: There's a Stack Exchange site dedicated to [Wordpress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) it accepts development questions.

Answer (score 0):

The hook you are looking for is to add actions to the sidebar; there are various ways - add_options_page will add to the options menu, for example. add_menu_page will create a new group for you to add your links.

Check the [documentation on adding admin menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Adding_Administration_Menus) for more information.

Comment: I have used the add_submenu_page already. The way it works is, you click on the edit products link in the admin menu and your presented with a list of products. The user then can click edit and be taken to a new page with the id passed so they can edit the product. I can get all working except for the edit part, I cant see how I can tell Wordpress to call the function that I want to use to edit a specific product.

Comment: Thread moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4677/how-to-create-and-link-to-administration-page-for-a-plugin